# Export Print Layouts with QMS Map Layers

Tags: qgis

I would like to export my map from the print composer that has a background layer from the QMS Quick Map Services plugin. I get this warning and then can't export the background layer:

> "Some WMS servers (e.g. UMN mapserver) have a limit for the WIDTH and
> HEIGHT parameter. Printing layers from such servers may exceed this
> limit. If this is the case, the WMS layer will not be printed"

Any suggestions or workarounds?

Comment: You could use a different WMS or create several smaller maps.

Comment: Do you know which WMS background would export?
Or do you know the limits for width and height that would work? I was trying to export on A4

Comment: Since I neither know your area of interest, nor your scale, nor the WMS you're using, I can't help you. Just try different WMS?

Comment: Okay then we keep looking for a solution. Asked here in lieu of testing the multitude of background maps offered and the scales at which i could potentially export them. Working around 1:80000 scale and ideally for google maps, hybrid, satellite, or any of the OSM backgrounds

Comment: How big an area are you trying to export? Using which Quick Map WMS layers?

Comment: I've tried on A0 page at 1:80000 scale with Google Maps/Satellite/Hybrid and OSM backgrounds. All works fine, without any error message.
Done with QGIS 3.10 x64 and QMS 0.19.11.1.